# How do I upload an image on my tkinter application without using Pillow?

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Gift-wrapping with Sally")

frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

... 

#Wallpaper Legnth
wallpaper_legnth_label = tkinter.Label(giftwrapping_frame, text= "How much wallpaper would you like? (Metres)")
wallpaper_legnth_spinbox = tkinter.Spinbox(giftwrapping_frame, from_= 0.5, to= 4)
wallpaper_legnth_label.grid (row= 1, column= 0)
wallpaper_legnth_spinbox.grid (row= 2, column= 0)

#Need to preview the two wallpaper prints to choose from
wallpaper_prints = tkinter.PhotoImage(file= r"C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject14\Wallpaper Prints.png")
wallpaper_prints_label = tkinter.Label
```

So, I dont know how to place the image within my survey as I have been using ".grid" to organise it according to how I want the layout to be.

I am unsure what my next line of code should be to place it

Comment: No, it doesn't make any difference what you name the root window. There are countless examples and tutorials that show how to use images in tkinter. It's not clear why you are having a problem. Please show what you've tried.

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments. You can [edit] your question to include more details.

Comment: Oh okay my bad my first time using this